# Binding a nullable int to an asp:TextBox

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, nullable

I have a property `int? MyProperty` as a member in my datasource (ObjectDataSource). Can I bind this to a TextBox, like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MyProperty") %>' />
```

Basically I want to get a `null` value displayed as blank `""` in the TextBox, and a number as a number. If the TextBox is blank `MyProperty` shall be set to `null`. If the TextBox has a number in it, MyProperty should be set to this number.

If I try it I get an exception: "Blank is not a valid Int32".

But how can I do that? How to work with nullable properties and Bind?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Well i've found a solution, which includes a FormView however and you don't specify if that fits your scenario.

Anyhow, in my case the DataBound-ed entity is a dto of my own (not that it should matter) and the trick is that when you update the formview you have to essentially attach on the pre-databound event and re-write the empty string as a null value so that the framework can property inject the value to the constructed object:

```
protected void myFormView_Updating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
     if (string.Empty.Equals(e.NewValues["MyProperty"]))
         e.NewValues["MyProperty"] = null;
}
```

and similarly on insert

```
protected void myFormView_Inserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
     if (string.Empty.Equals(e.Values["MyProperty"]))
         e.Values["MyProperty"] = null;
}
```

what makes this *really* fun is the fact that the error message ( is not a valid Int32) is actually wrong and it should write ( is not a valid Nullable) but then nullables would have been first class citizens wouldn't they?

Answer (score 2):

I'm starting to believe it's not possible to bind a nullable value property. Til now I only can see the workaround to add an additional helper property to bind a nullable type:

```
public int? MyProperty { get; set; }

public string MyBindableProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (MyProperty.HasValue)
            return string.Format("{0}", MyProperty);
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }

    set
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            MyProperty = null;
        else
            MyProperty = int.Parse(value);
            // value should be validated before to be an int
    }
}
```

and then bind the helper property to the TextBox instead of the original:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server"
    Text='<%# Bind("MyBindableProperty") %>' />
```

I'd be happy to see another solution.

Comment: This doesn't work inside a `FormView` where the datasource is an `EntityDataSource` -- I just get `DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceWrapper' does not contain a property with the name 'MyBindableProperty'.`

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" 

Text='<%# Bind("MyProperty").HasValue ? Bind("MyProperty") : "" %>' />
```

You could use HasValue to determine if the nullable type is null, and then set the Text property.

Comment: Thanks for reply, enduro. But this does not work at all and even does not compile. It would work with Eval (at least after casting the return of Eval to int?) but Bind is a whole other story.